# how to check database record counts using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Iam new in laravel ..i have 2 db tables   1.album(id,albumname,galimg_id) and 2.galleries(id,galname,galimg,album_id)
the album_id form album table(id)using foreign key

```
id  galname     galimg      album_id    
1   play       home/a1.jpg    1     
2   a6         home/a6.jpg     1    
3   school    school/sli1.JPG   2   
4   display    school/sli2.jpg     2 
6   archbishop  staff/archbi.jpg    4   
7   hm          staff/headmaster.jpg      4     
9   a5          school/a5.jpg              2
```

uploaded image count of each album_id is 5.(count=5)
    Ihave a problem  when am trying to insert an image into album_id(2) how to check the upload image count is>5 or <5 .if >5 image is insert into database wit corrsetponding album_id. otherwise give an error message(max 5 images).
My controller.php code is here

```
$id=Input::get('id');
  $f1=Input::get('f1');
  $file=Input::file('galimg');
  $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName(); //save img name into database
  $file->move('img/Albums/'.$f1,$filename);
 $c=5;
if(ForumGallery::find('id')->count()<$c)
  {
  ForumGallery::create([
  'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
  'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename,
  'album_id'=>Input::get('f2'),
  ]); 
  }
```

but i got an error message is Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your If statement:

```
if(ForumGallery::find('id')->count()<$c)
```

Try is like this:

```
if(ForumGallery::where('album_id', $theAlbumID)->count()<$c)
```

**EDIT:**
Re moved the `->get()` as suggested.

Comment: You can call `count()` directly without `get()` this way SQL does the counting and not all the rows have to be fetched and then counted in PHP.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't 100% sure when writing the answer. Tried to be quick and be the first one to answer :-D

Comment: sir ,,im using this code if(ForumGallery::where('album_id', $theAlbumID)->count()<$c) 
.my controller.php code is         $id=Input::get('id');
      $f1=Input::get('f1');
      $file=Input::file('galimg');
      $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName(); 
      $file->move('img/Albums/'.$f1,$filename);
if(ForumGallery::where('album_id', $theAlbumID)->count()<$c)
       { ForumGallery::create(['galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
      'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename,  'album_id'=>Input::get('f2'),
      ]);   } what  $theAlbumID?.1 error msg  ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Undefined variable: theAlbumID

Comment: thank you sir  its work ...i change this code ..im use this code   if(ForumGallery::where('album_id', $f2)->count()<$c) ...its work ..thank you for you suggesion.